# Drupal module: create a text format

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've created a module which defines a new *text format filter*.
Now I want to define a *text format* using this new filter, directly from module php. Drupal Administrator can do this manually from `admin/config/content/formats/add` admin page, but I want to avoid this step. What do I need to add to `my_dmodule.module`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to create a text format on module installation. If so, you could call filter_format_save(). The details on creating the object can be found in filter.module ([Drupal API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_format_save/7)).

You might have to load the filter module first if you are creating the filter in hook_install(), haven't checked:

```
drupal_load('module', 'filter');
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes simple solutions are hidden, especially in Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by *Hendrik*'s answer, this is my solution:

```
function myformat_install() {
  drupal_load('module', 'filter');
  /* check already exists */
  $format_exists = (bool) db_query_range('SELECT 1 FROM {filter_format} WHERE name = :name', 0, 1, array(':name' => 'My Format'))->fetchField();
  if (!$format_exists) {
    $format = array(
        'format' => 'myformat',
        'name' => 'My Format',
        'filters' => array(
            'myformat_filter' => array(
                'weight' => 0,
                'status' => 1,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $format = (object) $format;
    filter_format_save($format);
  }
}
```

`myformat_filter` is a filter defined implementing `hook_filter_info()`, but it could be a filter defined in another module.